# Hide/close button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have created a div box which should be removed on a click. There would be a small "X" image and when you click on it the box disappears. There shouldn't be an option to show it again. Ideally, I'd like to somehow save the information to the cookie, so that it doesn't appear on the page refresh or when viewing other pages (it would be implemented site-wide).

Here is my simple example code:

http://jsfiddle.net/2gNrC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty: (http://jsfiddle.net/bambitlaw/RsS5V/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#closebutton').click(function(){
    $('#box').hide();
    $(this).hide();
    document.cookie="hideit=yes";
});    
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x=="hideit")
   {
    $('#box').hide();
    $('#closebutton').hide();
    }
  }
```

});

Comment: I used this one, only replaced "hide" with "remove" in order to avoid display:none in css.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses `localStorage` - I leave it as an exercise to the reader to switch to using cookies:

http://jsfiddle.net/aTKs5/7/

Comment: Thanks, this one works greatin JSfiddle! I'll try to implement it live and let you know.

Comment: It doesn't work when online. Did I wrap it correctly? The script is in the head with the following code: <script type="text/javascript">

$('#closebutton').click(function(){$('#box').hide();if (localStorage) {localStorage.boxHidden = 'Y';}});

$(document).ready(function(){if (localStorage && localStorage.boxHidden && localStorage.boxHidden == 'Y'){$('#box').hide();}});

</script>

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to wrap everything in `$(document).ready()` as I should have done from the start - sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about a jquery dialog. I generally use "X"  the character itself and  it looks good. A sample as follows.

```
    $('#yourdiv').dialog({
        closeOnEscape: true,
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        closeText: 'X',
        width: 500,
        title: 'Your Title',
        buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Save",
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }

                ]
    });
```